Why my Rho-square on Multinomial Logit Model (McFadden) so small?
When I'm using MNL, and try to find my rho square, it's found out to be so small. It is $0.0139$. For a good fit model, the rho square has to be between $0.2$-$0.4$. Is there any reason why it's so small? How do I fix it?
Here is the log-likelihood value:


This is worth a read.

$R^2$ measures do not assess goodness of fit.  They quantify predictiveness of outcomes.  $R^{2}=0$ may be an excellent fit, i.e., every observation may have the same probability of an outcome.  Some outcomes are just hard to predict.  Some sets of predictors are just without predictive value.  To assess goodness of fit it’s usually best to posit an alternative, more flexible model and see how move the -2 log likelihood changes.
